# 2d geometry drawing tool

Tags: linux, language-agnostic, geometry

I'm looking for some tool/library that is able to draw simple 2d geometries from text file or programatically. I already found [List of interactive geometry software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interactive_geometry_software) but that not quite what I'm looking for. I would prefer something more similar in usage to graphviz or gnuplot. I already wrote some scripts for gnuplot but this tool has been designed for different purposes. Required functionality:

- support for different kind of 2D geometries: points, segments, lines, circles, polygons
- simple input type format maybe similar to postgis [Well Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)
- support for objects additional data like tags and colors definition
- output in common image format or some kind of interactive GUI (with zoom in/out and select object)
- configurable grid
- autoscale or draw in defined area

I will use it for testing geometry algorithms and don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but more a suggestion of where to look for an answer...  You should look for toolkits that have SVG output.  Several good interactive geometry programs (inkscape for example) support SVG editing and creation.  And it's not very hard to create SVG files.  I've written Python scripts that do it without the help of a toolkit.  I wanted to programmatically generate part of an art project.

Comment: The temptation to suggestion [QuickDraw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickDraw) has been ruthlessly suppressed. That is all.

Comment: Is QuickDraw only for MacOS? I should have mentioned I'm looking for some Linux tool :)

Comment: You are willing to code Python (read almost English), right?

Comment: QuickDraw is now deprecated (fully replaced by Quartz) and not even shipping in Mac OS X, but it seems you [can look at the source code](http://www.computerhistory.org/highlights/macpaint/). It only came to mind because the `PICT` format was just a list of coded QuickDraw commands, so it was east to construct a text language for it...

Comment: @Ashish: If it can be coded in python without lot of effort I can try.

Answer (score 3):

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). I'm not familiar with all the aspects of this Python library but I've heard it is pretty good.

To quote their introduction,

> matplotlib is a python 2D plotting
>   library which produces publication
>   quality figures in a variety of
>   hardcopy formats and interactive
>   environments across platforms.
>   matplotlib can be used in python
>   scripts, the python and ipython shell
>   (ala MATLAB®* or Mathematica®†), web
>   application servers, and six graphical
>   user interface toolkits.
>
> matplotlib tries to make easy things
>   easy and hard things possible. You can
>   generate plots, histograms, power
>   spectra, bar charts, errorcharts,
>   scatterplots, etc, with just a few
>   lines of code. For a sampling, see the
>   screenshots, thumbnail gallery, and
>   examples directory
>
> [image: Example outputs]
>   <sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/logo_sidebar_horiz.png))</sub>

>

> For example, using "ipython -pylab" to
>   provide an interactive environment, to
>   generate 10,000 gaussian random
>   numbers and plot a histogram with 100
>   bins, you simply need to type
>
> ```
> x = randn(10000)
> hist(x, 100)
> ```
>
> For the power user, you have full
>   control of line styles, font
>   properties, axes properties, etc, via
>   an object oriented interface or via a
>   set of functions familiar to MATLAB
>   users. The pylab mode provides all of
>   the pyplot plotting functions listed
>   below, as well as non-plotting
>   functions from numpy and
>   matplotlib.mlab.

Comment: [This](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/compound_path.html) example looks quite similar to what I want. I'm gonna give it a try.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/), with it's SVG output option is what you're looking for?  It can be scripted in Python.

Comment: I know dia but always have always thought about it as diagram/UML tool not geometry. Can you provide any tutorial on scripting dia in python?

Comment: @jethro - I've never done it.  I just know it can be done.  dia is rather poorly documented.  :-(